# Itextsharp Pdfreader Lock the file, how can I avoid it?

Tags: c#, itext, windows-services, pdf-reader, locked-files

I refer to this post:
[How to decrypt a pdf file by supplying password of the file as argument using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014148/how-to-decrypt-a-pdf-file-by-supplying-password-of-the-file-as-argument-using-c)

(In this post I cannot answer due to reputation, so please help me)

The exact solution in that post is the one I've been using for years.
This is the code

```
private void DecryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
   string password = @"secret"; // Your Key Here
   enter code here
   try
   {
      // the file crashes after this instruction
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputFile, new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(password));

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream);
            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
            File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile, memoryStream.ToArray());
        }

    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly, but if the password is wrong there is a big problem.

The file is locked by the application.
In my case the problem is even greater since it is not a windows application, but a windows service, therefore telling the customer "stop the service and delete the file" is not an optimal solution.

How can I prevent the file from getting stuck?

Comment: I would assume the `PdfReader` implements `IDisposable`, so it should probably be in a `using(...)` statement.

Comment: Indeed, putting the reader into a `using(...)` would be the first step. And if that doesn't suffice for which reason ever, consider first loading the file into a byte array and initializing the `PdfReader` from that byte array.

Comment: If `PdfReader` can take a stream, that might be a better alternative, since you can ensure that the stream is always disposed, even if the `PdfReader` does not do it. If neither works you should contact the vendor to make them fix their buggy implementation. If a class creates a resource, it should ensure proper disposal, even if an exception occurs.

Comment: The problem is that these operations are done on many files with FileSystemWatcher and with Multi Thread. I tried using Using (...), it partially solves. I moved 4 files, the first 3 are not blocked, the last yes. With two files, the first does not block the last yes etc...